# How do I get 'Content-Length' via javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following snippet:

```
var size;
function getImageSize(url) 
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if (xhr.status == 200) 
            {
                size = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
                alert(size);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
    return size;
}
```

The purpose of the function is to return the file size (of a image).

The alert inside the function will always return the correct value, however the function itself will always return `undefined`. Why?

Odly, if I debug it with firebug, the function will always return correctly...

Comment: If at all possible, I would create an ajax call that can just return the size of the image so you don't have to transfer it over the network just to know its size, but the question is still valid as an exercise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the function returns before the response is returned and the `size` is set. It's namely executed asynchronously. You'd like to pass a callback function instead and apply it with `size` as argument.

Comment: I thought of that... Using date objects I've had the function wait 5 seconds before returning. Still returned undefined.

Comment: @srcspider Don't return `size` (will will always be undefined there). Instead, pass in a callback to getImageSize which *is called from within the AJAX callback* where you read the content-length. Pass in the size as an argument to the callback. Another approach is to use a *synchronous* AJAX request, but that is *generally inadvisable* as it blocks and may lead for a very unresponsive solution.

Comment: @srcspider: you may find [jQuery](http://jquery.com) interesting. Take a closer look at the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. There's a `success` option wherein you can pass a callback function which will be executed when the response has been returned. jQuery offers more advantages as well. Go check it out :)

Comment: This question has been asked a million times before in slightly different ways. Many people have difficulty with asynchronous code. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340341/waiting-for-readystate-to-be-4-before-returning-a-value/4340504#4340504

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a code order problem there, that code is not synchronous, it is asynchronous.

The callback happens in the future, whereas the return happens straight away.

The reason debugging it in Firebug results in the return being correct, is that slows the code down long enough for the callback to have executed before you get to the return.